# Android Xamarin - How To Add Animations To View's Position Changes?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I'm a bit of a newb in Android. I've read a few tutorials but found it extensively complicated to understand. I was hoping someone can help me understand on how to implement Animations to views on the current context I'm working on (noob friendly).

Let's say this is my .axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Now this is my activity (Not exactly but enough information to know what I want to do:

```
private LinearLayout _topContainer;
private IDictionary<string, FrameLayout> _framelayoutViewsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, FrameLayout>();
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    //SetContentView and other stuff...
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 1);
    _topContainer = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.top_container);
}


public void CreateFirstVideoPlayer
{
    _framelayoutViewsDictionary.Add(Constants.Views.TOP_FRAMELAYOUT, new FrameLayout(this)
    {
        Id = 1,
        LayoutParameters = layoutParams
    });

    var fragmentManager = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    fragmentManager.Add(_framelayoutViewsDictionary[Constants.Views.TOP_FRAMELAYOUT].Id, /*Create New MediaPlayer Here*/, Constants.FragmentTag.TOP_FRAGMENT);
    fragmentManager.Commit();
    _topContainer.AddView(_framelayoutViewsDictionary[Constants.Views.TOP_FRAMELAYOUT]);
}

public void CreateSecondVideoPlayer
{
    _framelayoutViewsDictionary.Add(Constants.Views.BOTTOM_FRAMELAYOUT, new FrameLayout(this)
    {
        Id = 2,
        LayoutParameters = layoutParams
    });

    var fragmentManager = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    fragmentManager.Add(_framelayoutViewsDictionary[Constants.Views.BOTTOM_FRAMELAYOUT].Id, /*Create New MediaPlayer Here*/, Constants.FragmentTag.BOTTOM_FRAGMENT);
    fragmentManager.Commit();
    _topContainer.AddView(_framelayoutViewsDictionary[Constants.Views.BOTTOM_FRAMELAYOUT]);
}
```

As you can see. I'm programmatically creating a new FrameLayout, adding a fragment on top. And then putting that FrameLayout on top view which is a LinearLayout. Now when I add the second FrameLayout. The first FrameLayout is halved and the second one is added. So now each FrameLayout is taking 50:50 space. So what I want to do is. When the second FrameLayout is added, I want the first FrameLayout to animate so it slowly moves upwards to the top half of the screen instead of instantly appearing on the top. And when I remove the second FrameLayout the first FrameLayout will slowly animate back to the centre of the screen.

Hope this all makes sense. If you need more info please comment!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Support Libraries to perform a fragment slide in/out is as easy as setting the Fragment's custom animations to the built-in resource `abc_slide_in_bottom` and `abc_slide_out_bottom` animations.

#### Example:

```
SupportFragmentManager
    .BeginTransaction()
    .SetCustomAnimations(
        Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_bottom, 
        Resource.Animation.abc_slide_out_bottom,
        Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_bottom, 
        Resource.Animation.abc_slide_out_bottom)
    .AddToBackStack(count.ToString())
    .Add(Resource.Id.linearLayout1, new AFragmentSubClass(), count.ToString())
    .Commit();
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sushi, not exactly what I was looking for but still looks good nevertheless. However, I'm not sure how to add "Resource.Animation" animations to my project. Could you give further details, please?

Comment: @J.Hasmukhlal Those resources are available via the support libraries

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the late reply. I'll report back once I tested it. It'll take a while as I'm working on other projects.